# Block with 'overflow: scroll' overlaps the shadow

Tags: html, css, overflow, shadow

I use one block on the left to show the list. And another to show detailed info, it has a shadow. When the left block has 'overflow: scroll' it starts to draw elements' background over the shadow.

```css
.div-left {
  float: left;
  width: 64px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.div-right {
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 64px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='div-left'>
    <div style="background-color: red;">1</div>
    <div style='background: white;'>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div style="background-color: red;">4</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div style='background: red;'>2</div>
    <div style='background: white;'>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div class='div-right'>Replaced CSS linter with Stylelint which<br>supports all modern syntax. JSHint<br>also got a big update lately, now supports<br>async/await<br>syntax! Replaced CSS linter<br>with Stylelint which supports all modern syntax. JSHint<br>also got a big update lately, now supports<br>async/await syntax!</div>
</div>
```

How to make the shadow to be drawn over the list?

Comment: increase the z-index of the left element

Comment: Your claim is not actually true. It's just an optical illusion. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/dgwtr29x/). Click the button to alternate and you'll notice the change in background of all elements with background. The red is a strong color and it looks like it's painted above the shadow. In reality, it has shadow like everything else. Also notice that, in Chrome, the scrollbar has a different background color than the rest of the div, which might also be a bit confusing.

Comment: Check the difference https://jsfiddle.net/8omyLegz/7/

Comment: How about this https://jsfiddle.net/z7062eao/

Comment: @Stickers yes! solution is to add to the right block "z-index: 1; position: relative;". Thank you. Can you post it as an answer, and i'll accept it.

Comment: Nice to hear that, posted below with some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `overflow: scroll` increases stacking order of the element.

You can simply add `position: relative` to the right column, to make it on top again, and `z-index` is optional in this case.

```css
.div-left {
  float: left;
  width: 64px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.div-right {
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 64px);
  position: relative; /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='div-left'>
    <div style="background-color: red;">1</div>
    <div style='background: white;'>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div style="background-color: red;">4</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div style='background: red;'>2</div>
    <div style='background: white;'>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div class='div-right'>Replaced CSS linter with Stylelint which<br>supports all modern syntax. JSHint<br>also got a big update lately, now supports<br>async/await<br>syntax! Replaced CSS linter<br>with Stylelint which supports all modern syntax. JSHint<br>also got a big update lately, now supports<br>async/await syntax!</div>
</div>
```